# Remove outline around button after tabbing out in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, button

[image: Image of problem]

I'm developing an interface for a Winforms C# application, and whenever tabbing out of the app into another, the button I clicked before tabbing out has this white outline around it. Is there any possible way to get rid of this? This is a default winforms button.

Comment: In your Buttons' `Paint` event: `Control ctrl = sender as Control; ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, ctrl.ClientRectangle, ctrl.BackColor, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);`. You also have the [ButtonRenderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.buttonrenderer)  class (see the example there).

Comment: possibly could move this comment to an `Answer` ?